# repeat same row in the SQL selection statement under some conditions

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database table has four columns called `"Courses(CourseID,CourseName,CreditHours,LabSession)"`, and I wanna write SQL Statement that retrieve all data in the Course table, furthermore, the SQL must repeat the row (record) if the LabSession column in the row has a value `"Y"` otherwise retrieve the row as it is without repeating.

BTW, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Database

Comment: Your reference to LabSession... Is there another table that is associated with the session that would indicate/represent multiple rows based on the type of lab session?  We would need to see that too, in order to help.

Comment: There is no reference table associated with LabSession Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select CourseID,CourseName,CreditHours,LabSession from Courses
union ALL
select CourseID,CourseName,CreditHours,LabSession from Courses where LabSession='Y'
order by CourseID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CourseID, CourseName, CreditHours, LabSession
FROM Courses
UNION ALL
SELECT CourseID, CourseName, CreditHours, LabSession
FROM Courses
WHERE LabSession = 'Y'
ORDER BY CourseId
```